# Extra whitespace in XML file read from Oracle database - why?

Tags: xml, oracle, xmltype

I am experimenting with Python and Oracle XML DB. I have a table with an XMLType column and an ID column in an Oracle 11g database. The storage model for the XML column is object relational. Sometimes I need to get a whole XML file, and often it is longer than 4000 characters, so I use this query to get a CLOB:

```
select t.representation.getclobval()
from myxmldocs t 
where id=:documentId
```

When I run this query the output includes extra whitespace, with newlines and tabs between XML elements that were definitely not there in the XML docs I inserted. The effect is of some kind of formatting, so that the output looks like this:

```
<A>\n
\t<B></B>\n
\t\t<C>Some text</C>\n
\t\t<C>Some more text</C>\n
\t<B></B>\n
...
```

and so on. Quite pretty and readable, but why am I getting it? It also messes other libraries that I am using that choke on the extra whitespaces.

If I remove getclobval() my Python client does not get a CLOB but an Object and I don't know what to do with it.

This appears consistent; I get this problem using the sqlplus command line client, and also creating other tables using different XML Schemas, and then querying them. In a previous version of my prototype I had the XMLType column use a CLOB storage model and didn't have this problem.

How should I rewrite the query to just get a CLOB with the XML file without the extra formatting?

---

Update: as requested in the comments, this is the output I get running the query `select dump(t.representation) from myxmldocs t where id=:documentId` from the command line client (replacing of course :documentId with an actual, existing ID from the database):

```
DUMP(T.REPRESENTATION)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Typ=58 Len=218: 32,156,148,1,0,0,0,0,80,193,223,20,0,0,0,0,216,15,47,21,0,0,0,0,
80,44,55,21,0,0,0,0,0,202,154,59,160,15,0,0,160,15,0,0,1,0,4,0,220,190,195,71,1,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,174,33,65,0,15,0,72,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,49,0
,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Comment: "It also messes other libraries that I am using that choke on the extra whitespaces." - those libraries are pretty poor then. Those whitespaces are perfectly legal XML.

Comment: Agreed, but I don't have control over the library, which provides a functionality that would really, really time consuming to reimplement from scratch.

Comment: @Btz, can you update your question with the results of the query: `select dump(t.representation) from  myxmldocs t where id=:documentId` ?

Comment: Just updated the question with the output of your query, @A.B.Cade .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in 11g you can use `xmlserialize` (in fact you should not use `getclobval` anymore. it's not recommended for performance reasons)

```
 SQL> select t.test.getclobval() from testxml t where id = 1;

T.TEST.GETCLOBVAL()
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<A>
  <B>
    <C>foo</C>
    <C>foo2</C>
  </B>
</A>


SQL> select xmlserialize(document t.test as clob no indent) from testxml t where id = 1;

XMLSERIALIZE(DOCUMENTT.TESTASCLOBNOINDENT)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<A><B><C>foo</C><C>foo2</C></B></A>
```

Comment: +1 for `XMLSERIALIZE`, I didn't know about it. Why do you say you shouldn't use `getClobVal()`? I was under the impression that this function performs *no* computation by itself!

Comment: @VincentMalgrat `getclobval` is superceeded by `xmlserialize`. Note  1407946.1 (performance guide for xml db) states `It is recommended to XMLSerialize since its optimized by the XDB and thus performs better rather than using getclobval(). In addition from 11.2.x onwards xmltype.getclobval function is deprecated anyway.`. Yes it doesn't reformat the XML, but in the case of object-relational the xml will always get pretty printed by default so we need to undo this with "no indent" (or as you've shown an XSL with strip + noindent in 10g and earlier).

Comment: Very interesting, I think I'll go for XMLSERIALIZE. However, I also managed to get this to work: `select to_clob(xmlquery('./node()' passing t.representation returning content)) from myxmldocs t where id=1`. Maybe this will work for those that use 10g, to avoid having to reformat the XML with XSLT? What is the disadvantage of using to_clob() in this case? The documentation says: _TO_CLOB converts NCLOB values in a LOB column or other character strings to CLOB values._ I wonder if that makes things difficult for documents with non-ASCII characters, such as Chinese?

Comment: @Btz i wouldn't use `to_clob()` over `getclobval()` in 10g (i'd still go with `xmlserialize` in the xquery version even on 10g. It will work just fine).

Answer (score 0):

The `getClobVal()` method shouldn't modify the indentation of data. Your XML may have been formatted during or before the insertion.

You can [transform](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/t_xml.htm#i1009783) the XMLType to remove whitespaces:

```
SQL> SELECT XMLTYPE.createxml(
  2  '<a>
  3     <b><c></c></b>
  4  </a>'
  5  ).transform(XMLTYPE(
  6  '<?xml version="1.0"?>
  7  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  8     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
  9     <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>
 10     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 11     <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
 12     <xsl:copy>
 13        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
 14     </xsl:copy>
 15  </xsl:template>
 16  </xsl:stylesheet>
 17  ')).getClobVal() FROM dual;

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<a><b><c></c></b></a>
```